# In clojure, why the type of an empty list is different from that of non-empty lists?

Tags: clojure

I want to judge if two values are of same type, but I found that the type of an empty list is `clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList` rather than `clojure.lang.PersistentList`.

```
user=> (def la '())
#'user/la
user=> (def lb '(1 2))
#'user/lb
user=> (def t (map type [la lb]))
#'user/t
user=> t
(clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList clojure.lang.PersistentList)
user=> (apply = t)
false
user=>
```

So, I'm wondering why is the type of an empty list different from that of non-empty lists and what's the correct way to tell if two things are of same type?

Comment: `EmptyList` is just implementation of IPersistentList and i suppose  it was created by only performance reason. And it seems there is not any other ways to compare types of two elements. But may be function `list?` will be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Don't** rely on the concrete types of Clojure data structures. They are undocumented implementation details, and you have no guarantee that they won't change in future versions of Clojure.

It is **much safer** to rely on the abstractions (e.g. as defined by the `IPersistentList` or `ISeq` interfaces). These are much less likely to change in ways that might break your code (my understanding is that Rich Hickey is very big on backwards compatibility when it comes to abstractions. If you depend on a concrete implementation, I believe he would say it's your own fault if things break)

But **even better**, you should use functions in `clojure.core` such as `seq?` or `list?`, depending on exactly what it is you want to detect. Not only are these likely to maintain backwards compatibility for a long time, they also have a chance of working correctly on non-JVM versions of Clojure (e.g. ClojureScript).